# Why is VS mac opening separate terminal windows when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio

When I start debugging one of my projects, **VS mac** automatically opens a terminal window (see image attached).

It (terminal) doesn't get closed when I stop debugging or close my project. I have to manually close each one.

I would like to know if I have some special setting turned on (or off) for this terminal window to appear, or if it is something specific to my project.

How to I prevent VS from opening this automatically?

[terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouvs4.png)